# Jenkins --- how to fail a job when net use command to map a drive fails

Tags: jenkins

I have the following script running as windowsbatch type

```
net use Q: \\ma-dev-cd1\c$\ >> C:\resful.txt 2>&1
xcopy c:\resful.txt z:\Build
```

how do I fail the job when it hasn't copied the file over for any reason?

Comment: errorlevel variable stores last command status, hence exit with it value `exit /b %errorlevel%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the copied file `resful.txt` exists at `z:\Build` or not. If it exists do nothing but if the file is not there then exit your Jenkins job with a `non-zero` code and it will make your job failed.

```
IF EXIST z:\Build\resful.txt (
    echo file exists
) ELSE (
    echo file doesn't exist
    EXIT /B 2
)
```

This should do the trick.